# R barplot: how to move x-axis' tick labels farther away from the axis

Tags: r

```
x <- barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), xaxt="n")
labs <- paste(names(table(mtcars$cyl)), "cylinders very long name")
text(cex=1, x=x-.25, y=-1.25, labs, xpd=TRUE, srt=45)
```

My tick labels are very long and overlap with the barplots. Is there a way to move them farther away from the x-axis? I've tried using `offset` in `text()` but that did not seem to work.[image]

Comment: set `y` in `text` to a smaller value like -5? With this, you also have to increase the margin of the plot.

Comment: you might want to just split it into multiple lines using a soft break escape character like \n ex: "4 cylinders\nvery long name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a combo of margins and text size:

```
# Ensure default R par() to start with
par(mar=c(7.7, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))
x <- barplot(table(mtcars$cyl), xaxt="n")
labs <- paste(names(table(mtcars$cyl)), "cylinders very long name")

text(cex=0.8, x=x-.25, y=-3.5, labs, xpd=TRUE, srt=45)
```

[image]